# How to append html anchor (link) to evernote note

Tags: macos, applescript, evernote

How can I append a html anchor (clickable link) to an Evernote note? The following gives me just the text in the note. Thanks.

```
set myLink to "<a html=\"" & currentTabUrl & "\">" & currentTabTitle & "</a>"
tell curnote to append html "<br/>" & myLink & return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not having any problems, just append as `html` not `text`. Here is the code...

```
#
# Based on https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/applescript.php
#

tell application "Evernote"
    set notebook1 to notebook "AppleScriptNotebook1"
    set mynotes to (get every note in notebook1 whose title is "Test")
    if (count of mynotes) is equal to 1 then
        set note1 to item 1 of mynotes
        tell note1 to append html "<br>"
        tell note1 to append html "<a href=\"https://google.com\">link text</a>"
    end if
end tell
```

Here is what it looks like and link worked just fine...

[image: Evernote with URL]

Comment: Thanks, it was a total typo on my point. I had html instead of href in the html text I was appending. My first line should be ```set myLink to "<a href=\"" & currentTabUrl & "\">" & currentTabTitle & "</a>"```